# How can I store my session storage to redis using django?

Tags: python, django, redis

I currently have my session storage in my db (postgreSql) and now I am moving towards redis to store the session data

I currently used redis for Django Cacheing Backend. Using, the package [django-redis-cache](https://django-redis-cache.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), this is currently what I have come upto in my settings.py file.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",     
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",        
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",       
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",       
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware'
]

SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'redis_cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': 'localhost:6379',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'DB': 1,
        },
    },
}
```

I expect the redis server to be used as a session storage.

Comment: And what happens when you try this?

Comment: It just does the cacheing in the backend. I want not only the cache but the overall session to be stored in redis.

Comment: what tells you it's not being used for the sessions?

Comment: @dirkgroten my sessions are still being stored in the database and not in redis.

Comment: but how do you know this? what are you checking that makes you think this? you say you're migrating from the old situation, so old sessions will still be in your db unless you delete them manually.